# FancyBox 2.1.5 not working with jQuery 1.10

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've just made the update to FancyBox 2.1.5 and jQuery 1.10, but since then FancyBox has stopped working, where each link reverts to its default behaviour.

I don't have any errors or warnings, it just doesn't work. I've tried:
1. different DOCTYPE;
2. different HMTL tag attributes;
3. declaring FancyBox inside and outside the header tag;
4. declaring the code for the FancyBox function inside and outside the header tag;
5. reducing the code down to the simplest practical state;
6. changing the class names;
7. using earlier versions of jQuery;
8. removing all parameters from the FancyBox function;
9. a multitude of combinations of 1-8.

Everything I've tried has failed.

Also, the demo works perfectly, though I cannot replicate it in my application.

Note: I CANNOT tame the list above to appear as anything even approaching sensible; it either appears as just 1 item or 8, even though there's 9 items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having scoured my application, I've discovered a working example, and it appears FancyBox is enforcing a strict usage policy, as it only works if there's a type attribute for the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.iframe").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': true,
        'height': 380,
        'padding': 0,
        'width': 700, 
        'type': 'iframe'
    });
});
```

Comment: if you are using `iframes` yes, you have to set the `type`, otherwise external pages would be loaded via `ajax` and may trigger js errors if the have their own independent scripts. BTW, `hideOnContentClick` is for fancybox v1.3.4 and it doesn't exist in v2.x

Comment: Thank you this fixed my problem. You should accept your own answer.

Comment: Just to add a little note to this answer for other folks (like me) with a similar problem: supported types are 'image', 'inline', 'ajax', 'iframe', 'swf' and 'html'. So if you use fancybox to open images then declare type: 'image'.